# Transcribe non-english audio to phonetically similar english words

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, phonetics

Essentially, if I have an audio file where someone is speaking, is there something I can use to match the audio to similar sounding English words.

For example, if a Spanish speaker said:

```
Hola, me llamo Bob y me gusta ir a la biblioteca.
```

The program would output something similar to:

```
old ahh may yam oh bob, E may goo star ear ala bib lee oh tech ah
```

As you can see from my very bad example, it doesn't need to be close to perfect, it just needs to be phonetically similar. I would prefer something that works with python, but at this point anything will be good.

Comment: This would be a hilarious party app for translating what people say on-the-fly into "Gringo"

Comment: Unfortunately, questions asking for tools or libraries are explicitly off-topic for stack overflow. I will note, though, that python does have a popular speech recognition module that could form a basis to start your research, then you could come ask a specific question with a [mcve] if you get stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very old reply, but I managed to do this with the Vosk transcription library